# Does Firefox 17 report correct scrollWidth?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I have html code in table like this

```
<td style="overflow: hidden"><a href="...">Very long text</a></td>
```

Text overflows cell, but FF 17 reports wrong scrollWidth. It's like clientWidth, so JS to show content does not work. Firebug reports width of content much larger than cell.

Is this FF bug, or something has changed in dom properties?
This code still works in Chromium and Opera.

Comment: I have the same bug. Try setting `overflow:auto`. FF seems to treat `visible` and `hidden` in a wrong way. Test your code in WebKit also please